# SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode with Riot/TypeScript

Tags: typescript, riot.js

Running:

```
riot --type typescript test.tag
```

I got the error:

```
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
```

How to fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that I was using Node version `v0.12.7`.

The problem went away when I upgraded to Node `v5.0.0`.

(For example, using Homebrew, it would be just a case of `brew upgrade node`.)